# Как разместить свой первый сайт в интернет?

Tags: css, html5, веб-программирование, веб-сайт

Учусь делать сайты, добрался до первого более-менее приличного сайта(HTML+CSS). Посоветуйте где и как выставить свою первую работу?(желательно бесплатно)

Comment: Github pages, например, aws s3...

Comment: github.io отлично подойдет для HTML+CSS, но не приучит к работе с ftp, установкой доменов и прочим, найдите несколько бесплатных или пробных хостингов и экспериментируйте

Comment: "желательно бесплатно" - если вы этим хотите заниматься в какой-то мере профессионально, то 1500р в год не жалко отдать и на хостинг, где вы будете царь и бог :)  с доступом к базам данных и т.д.

Comment: естественно, я хочу заниматься этим на высоком уровне, просто сейчас хочу глянуть как оно все работает (как выставляется и прочее). Может вы подскажите какую-то литературку или статью?)

Comment: Github pages или sprinthost free

Comment: «Выставляется» у всех по-разному

Comment: На www.narod.ru

Answer (score 0):

Многие хостинги имеют бесплатный тестовый период и предоставляют технический домен, так же у них написаны подробные руководства по началу работы.  Если же оплатить 1 месяц ( 100 - 200 рублей ) самого простого тарифа, то и техподдержка становится лояльней - охотней отвечают и помогают.
Но по мне так лучше воспользуйтесь GitHub.io, создайте свой первый репозиторий, создайте свою первую ветку и залейте туда свой сайт. Знание этого сервиса всё равно понадобится, так что убьёте двух зайцев - освоите Git/GitHub и получите бесплатный хостинг.